# DAGitty Question: Testable Implications only describes independencies, but not dependencies

Tags: r, causality

Why does the DAGitty "Testable Dependencies" function only describe independencies, but not spurious correlations?

E.g, if I have B->A<-C,
DAGitty just tells me that
B ⊥ C is the only testable (in)dependency
Why shouldn't we expect also
B⊥̸C|A
(i.e, B and C may have a spurious correlation given A)?[image]

Comment: The dependencies are the complement of the independencies - so what would be the additional information in listing both?

Answer (score 0):

When choosing among several causal models (a DAG and a set of parameters for it), there must be some criteria which restrict the number of acceptable models, otherwise there would be an infinite number of equally valid causal models for any arbitrary data.

One of the criteria is *Occam's Razor*: we choose the *minimal* causal model, *i.e.* the causal model which has the least number of nodes in the DAG and the least number of parameters.

However, even employing Occam's Razor, there is the possibility that there are multiple minimal models: given a DAG, there are several parameterizations we may select. In order to choose among these minimal models, one tiebreaking criterion is *stability* . This is the assumption that all the independencies in the joint probability distribution $P$ equivalent to the chosen DAG are stable, *i.e.* they are invariant to any change in parameters. For a much more detailed discussion, see Pearl`s *Causality* (2nd edition, 2009, p. 45).

That might be one reason why DAGitty lists the independencies in each given DAG: any joint distribution must obey these independencies, otherwise they are not stable.